# how to compare table to it self and get the rows with same data in just one column?

Tags: mysql

how can i compare a table to it self because i need to retrieve the student’s id number that get same grade in different courses, and display their id number, course id number, and the grade that are the same.
I've tried this code:

```
select sno,cno,score from subjcode where (select count(distinct score) from subjcode)>1;
```

but it is not correct because the output should be

```
S003    C001    81.90
S003    C002    81.90
```

only

the table is named subjcode:

```
sno     cno     score
S001    C001    78.90
S001    C002    82.90
S001    C003    59.00
S002    C001    80.90
S002    C002    72.90
S003    C001    81.90
S003    C002    81.90
S004    C001    60.90
```

thanks for help!

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an inner join to itself, by score, the common field you search for. Then, you choose from that, diferent rows that have score repeated more than one time. Should be this way.

```
select distinct A.cno, A.sno, B.score from subjcode A
inner join subjcode B on (B.score = A.score)
group by A.cno, A.sno
having count(B.score) > 1;
```

Comment: i'm voting but idk why it says"vote cast by those with less than 15 reputation can be recorded" :(

Comment: Just to avoid spamming or robot bots from not usual users...:) dont worry.